# Minimum energy of proton converting into a neutron

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, mass, neutrons, protons

I'm given the isotope sodium 22 (which is positron emitter) and I'm stuck with calculating the minimum energy that a proton needs to convert into a neutron and a positron.

It got to do with $E=MC^2$ but with which masses do I calculate now specifically?

My first calculation was $22na - (22ne +electron)$ and my second one was $(11*mp)+(11mn)-(22na)$ but now I am confused - what did I calculate with my first attempt and what with the second one? Is one of them correct for my task or both wrong?

Notice: When I mention an element in an equation it means I'm using the atomic mass of it (atomic mass of 22 na, 22ne, electron, and so on)

Comment: Search term: [mass excess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_excess)

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out after figuring it out both attempts were wrong

In this specific case it has nothing to do with the isotope it's just "mass of proton - (mass of neutron + mass of electron)" and with that one need to calculate the energy coming from that mass defect - pretty simple